# Joining over separate lists

Tags: r, list, join

I have two separate lists, one containing the ID of individuals, the other one containing different attributes of the individuals; in this case 3 different states "a", "b" and "c". Both lists contain 4 different points in time: "p1", "p2", "p3" and "p4".

```
#create ID in period 1,2,3,4
id <- list(p1=sample(c(1:5)),
           p2=sample(c(1:6)),
           p3=sample(c(3:6)),
           p4=sample(c(3:8)))
id
$p1
[1] 4 3 1 2 5

$p2
[1] 6 2 5 3 1 4

$p3
[1] 3 6 5 4

$p4
[1] 7 5 8 3 4 6


#create states in period 1,2,3,4
states <- list(p1=sample(c("a","b","c"),5,replace=TRUE),
                  p2=sample(c("a","b","c"),6,replace=TRUE),
                  p3=sample(c("a","b","c"),4,replace=TRUE),
                  p4=sample(c("a","b","c"),6,replace=TRUE))
states
$p1
[1] "a" "c" "a" "b" "c"

$p2
[1] "c" "c" "b" "b" "c" "a"

$p3
[1] "b" "c" "b" "a"

$p4
[1] "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "b"
```

The ordering of the vectors is correct, i.e. whoever has position 3 in the ID vector will have position 3 in the states vector in this period. Please note that different periods both have some different individual IDs as well as a different number of observations. Now I want to efficiently match the individual IDs over the time periods 1-4 and have a look at the individual states over time. The goal is this:

```
ID p1 p2 p3 p4
1  a  c  NA NA
2  b  c  NA NA
3  c  b  b  b
...
```

My first intuition would have been to create 4 data.frames and join them, however, that seems very inefficient as well as does not give me information of where to put NAs when individuals are not present in a period.
Any help is appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. The logic behind it is that individual 1 had state "a" in p1, "c" in p2 and then dropped out of the sample. Individual 3 had states "c", "b", "b", "b" in periods 1 to 4 (which correspond to "positions" 2,4,1,4 in the corresponding vectors).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I got it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `melt` the datasets then do a reshape

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
melt(id, value.name = 'id') %>%
    mutate(value2 = melt(states)[,1]) %>%        
    spread(L1, value2)
#  id   p1   p2   p3   p4
#1  1    a    c <NA> <NA>
#2  2    b    c <NA> <NA>
#3  3    c    b    b    b
#4  4    a    a    a    c
#5  5    c    b    b    b
#6  6 <NA>    c    c    b
#7  7 <NA> <NA> <NA>    a
#8  8 <NA> <NA> <NA>    b
```

#### data

```
id <- list(p1 = c(4, 3, 1, 2, 5), p2 = c(6, 2, 5, 3, 1, 4), 
       p3 = c(3, 6, 5, 4), p4 = c(7, 5, 8, 3, 4, 6))
states = list(p1 = c('a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'), p2 = c('c', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a'),
      p3 = c('b', 'c', 'b', 'a'), p4 = c('a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'b'))
```